# Convergence of semi-implicit Euler scheme for SDE

Tags: numerical-methods, brownian-motion, finance, stochastic-differential-equations, eulers-method

I am confronted with the following problem: For $W$ being a one-dimensional brownian motion and $\alpha\in[0,1]$, what are the conditions for the numerical scheme

$X_{n+1}=X_n+(1-\alpha)\mu X_n\Delta t+\alpha \mu X_{n+1}\Delta t + \sigma X_n\Delta W$

(which I understand to be the semi-implicit Euler scheme for a geometric brownian motion) such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(X^2_n)=0$ holds?

I have already proven that  $2\mu+\sigma^2<0$ is the condition such that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(X^2(t))=0$ holds for a geometric brownian motion $dX=\mu X dt + \sigma X dW_t$ so naturally I assume that the answer must also depend on the time steps $\Delta t$ and the parameter $\alpha$?

My inital approach to the problem was to express the expectation in terms of the mean square error of the scheme but I have not been able to do so yet.

Any clues or ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you explain your first condition? I get $d(X_t^2)=(2μ+σ^2)X_t^2\,dt+2σX_t^2\,dW_t$, so that $2μ+σ^2<0$ is necessary for the expectation to fall to zero.

Comment: Yes you are right, there was initially a typo in my question:

By applying Itô's Lemma the solution to the geometric brownian motion SDE becomes $X(t)=X(0) \exp((\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)+\sigma W(t))$ so $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(X^2(t))=\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}(X(0)^2)\exp((2\mu+\sigma^2)t)=0$ which leads to $2\mu+\sigma^2<0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the terms of the dynamic
$$
(1-αμΔt)X_{n+1}=(1+(1−α)μΔt+σΔW)X_n
$$
Take the square  and the expectation of it. Remember that the increment of the Brownian motion is independent of the history so far.
\begin{align}
(1-αμΔt)^2E[X_{n+1}^2]&=E[(1+(1−α)μΔt+σΔW)^2]\,E[X_n^2]
\\
&=\Bigl((1+(1−α)μΔt)^2+σ^2Δt\Bigr)\,E[X_n^2].
\end{align}
So for the convergence to zero you want
$$
(1+(1−α)μΔt)^2+σ^2Δt<(1-αμΔt)^2
\\\iff\\
2(1−α)μ+σ^2+(1−α)^2μ^2Δt<-2αμ+α^2μ^2Δt
\\\iff\\
2μ+σ^2<(2α-1)μ^2Δt
$$

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for